# Companion commander question

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Haven't seen this covered, but can you use a companion card such as [Jegantha, the Wellspring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJegantha%2c%20the%20Wellspring%5d) as your commander instead of as a companion?
The text on the card reads If this card is your chosen companion you may cast it once from outside the game. 
Does this mean if I don't choose it as a companion I can use it like any other regular legendary creature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

The Companion keyword only functions outside of the game. This means that if a card with Companion is in your deck, whether as a Commander or just any regular card, then the Companion part of the card doesn't do anything; it's just a normal creature. In the case of a Commander deck, it would just be a normal Legendary Creature which is therefore valid as your Commander.

> 702.138. Companion
>
> > 702.138a Companion is a keyword ability **that functions outside the game**. It’s written as “Companion—[Condition].” Before the game begins, you may reveal one card you own from outside the game with a companion ability whose condition is fulfilled by your starting deck. (See rule 103.1b.) If you do, once during that game, you may play that card from outside the game.
>
> 903. Commander
>
>      > 903.3. Each deck has **a legendary creature card** designated as its commander. This designation is not a characteristic of the object represented by the card; rather, it is an attribute of the card itself. The card retains this designation even when it changes zones.

[Jegantha, the Wellspring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJegantha%2c%20the%20Wellspring%5d) is a legendary creature, therefore it can be your Commander.

Comment: Wonderful. I wasn't sure if companion was a requirement or a choice. Thank you!

Comment: @ragazinski If this answer was helpful and a better one doesn’t come along, please mark it as “accepted”, thanks!

Comment: In this case then, the deck wouldn't have to meet the companion condition?

Comment: @BadPirate Correct.. the entire companion ability would just be ignored as if it weren’t there.